# Where is jQuery get?

Tags: jquery

I was using `getJSON` but it didn't worked the way I expected, the `WebService` was returning `xml` even thought specifically specified as `ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.JSON`. After reading some post(s) on the internet I found that the problem was `getJSON` won't set the `contentType` to `application/json; charset=utf8`, rather it lets it be default. I verified it by calling `$.ajax` and setting `contentType` to `application/json; charset=utf8`. So I though to look into `jQuery-1.9.1.js` and find out how `getJSON` is implemented. Here's the exact signature from the file...

```
getJSON: function( url, data, callback ) {  // line 8107 as of 1.9.1.js
    return jQuery.get( url, data, callback, "json" );
}
```

So, I looked further to find how is `jQuery.get` implemented. But to my utmost surprise I can't find any??? I looked many times, but there is no `get` defined in the file that takes `4` or more arguments? How could this be? If it is not defined, how is `get`, and by extension `getJSON` (and also `getScript`) are getting called? Can anyone please check and verify this?

ps: please don't tell me I can use `ajaxSetup` etc. and there are other ways to do it, I know, but what's puzzling my mind is, I couldn't find `jQuery.get` definition, so how and from where is it getting called?

Comment: @gaurav: I know that page man! I am saying where is `get` in the `js` file? I can't find any that takes 4 args (or more). I know the page on site about documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 197 of the [`ajax.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L197-214) file is where the `get` and `post` functions are defined:

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
        // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            dataType: type,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        });
    };
});
```

As you can see they are simply calling the `jQuery.ajax` method.

Comment: That's it! Nailed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js

Specifically line 197-214.

They pass through `get` and `post` to `jQuery.ajax()`